# How to convert utf-8 string to big5 and print it with java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, character

Is there any way to convert utf-8 string to big5 output? I know by default Java output the string with utf-8 (or the system default machine setting), but I don't know how to output the string with big5 encoding. I'm using the `System.out.println(myString)` to output the string and then redirect to a file. It seems no `println` method can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your file as UTF-8
   (in Eclipse: right click the file → Properties → Resource → Text file encoding: Other UTF-8)
2. Try to print text like this:

   ```
   Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
   System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream fos;
final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fox, "big5");

writer.write(myString);
writer.newLine();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

If you are wanting to write to `System.out` you will have no control over the character encoding. It will be the default for the platform.

Comment: I use shell script to redirect the output of the java program. If I output to the file, then I have to write it to a temporarily file and process it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the system property `file.encoding` to big5 when launching the jvm?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to print do it.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "BIG5");
out.println(myString);
```

In this way I can print the big5 encoded string to standard output.